# How to link four tables avoiding N-ary association

Tags: sql, database

I have those four tables in database :

```
USER
id

PERMISSION
id

OBJECT
id

CONTEXT
id
```

Now the problem is that I want to link them to say that a user has one or many permissions on one or many objects depending of a context.. It looks simple but I can't find a way to avoid n-ary association..

Hope someone will be kind enough helping me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for something like a [**WEAK ENTITY**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity)

Basically, a weak entity is a database entity which doesn't make sense on its own, but needs one (or more) foreign keys to assume a proper identity and a meaning.

This means that you're moving from an N-ary relationship to N binary relationships.

One possible approach is this: let's say that we call this weak entity `Rules`

```
Rules(id, user_id, permission_id, object_id, context_id /*other columns*/);
```

each of your strong entities has a relationship with the rules table. I don't like a lot this approach, but for small datasets it may work pretty well.

As a general note, though, I suggest you to think a bit more about your database model: are you absolutely, positively sure that all these 4 entities have a so strong relationship together? For example, does "Context" has influence on users, objects and permissions or just on permissions? Does an object exists at the same time across multiple contexts, or it makes sense to bind an object inside a specific context (the same concept of a variable scope)?

Comment: Hi, you suggest that instead of doing N-ary associations, I could do N-binary associations.. Okay, but you proposed to create a join table containing each primary keys of the four objects, so it's still an N-ary association, no ?

Comment: well, yes and no. Now it's an entity with N binary associations, rather than a relationship between N tables. I see that they look similar, but with your current design i can't see many alternatives.